# Движение объекта по дуге в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-canvas

Задача такая. Нарисовать на форме дугу и строго по ней двигать объект `Image` из кода в зависимости от полученных данных. Дугу я нарисовал. А вот как по ней двигать объект из кода?

```
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <PathGeometry x:Key="Animation" >
            <PathFigure IsClosed="False" StartPoint="100,100">
                <ArcSegment Point="200,100" Size="50,50" SweepDirection="Clockwise" />
            </PathFigure>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Path x:Name="ArcPath" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="191" Width="320" Stretch="Fill" Margin="13,10,0,0" Data="{StaticResource Animation}" />
    <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="Images/my.png" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="6,186,0,0" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Найдите параметрические уравнения дуги в интернете и воспользуйтесь ими для расчета текущих координат объекта в зависимости от времени. Время пусть вам отмеряет, например, таймер

Comment: вот ту есть пример https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/16.4.php

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.